# Fetching URL Based on InnerText C#

Tags: c#, regex, html-agility-pack

I would like to fetch a URL from an `html` or string based on the inner text value.

For Example:

```
<a href="http://www.itsmywebaddress.com">My Website</a>.
<a href="http://www.everythingisforgood.com">good</a>.
```

Here, I need to fetch the URL based on the inner text of "My Website" (which we provide as input).

Can anyone tell me , what is the `Regex` code for this or using `HtmlAgilityPack` how can we do this??

I have used the following `Regex` method . However, its fetching all the values inside the "a" tag.

```
Regex.Match(str, @"<a [^>]*>(.*?)</a>").Groups[1].Value;
```

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(url);
var hrefs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
             .Where(link => link.InnerHtml == str)
             .Select(l=>l.Attributes["href"].Value).ToList();
```

Comment: But it will fetch all the urls in the htmldocument. But i want to fetch the url which contains the innertext of some string we given as input

Comment: Then you can add the required condition the .Where(...) statement

Comment: sorry , Following error occurs : System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1[HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode]

Comment: string hrefs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]").Where(link => link.InnerHtml =="My Website").ToString();

Comment: you can't call `ToString` like that, check my update, it will return `href` values as List which match your condition

Answer (score 0):

If you are using htmlagility, you should be able to access the href directly without having to use a regex.

Something like this should work;

```
HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(url);
foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{
HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["href"];
}
```

Comment: yup ..it will fetch all the links in the htmldocument .. but i want to fetch the url based on the innertext which we provide